# Error while npm install in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Im new to Angular JS. I'm following the tutorial which is provided in Angular JS website. I've cloned the git project and when I try for npm install it gives me errors like

```
npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: shelljs
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-    client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/bigc/Angular-Tutorial/angular-phonecat/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-23-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/bigc/Angular-Tutorial/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: shelljs
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/bigc/Angular-Tutorial/angular-phonecat/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Do I need to do anything other than cloning?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

when i started sometimes i have foun error too with cloning git repository, make a check for your version of github and update it if you need it, after you do that you can go directly to angularjs's github page, the tutorial you want to see it's in the sample folder, you cant take it form here or cloning directly from the address write on the right of the page.

Comment: I found the solution. The issue comes when I don't have the latest version of node.js. After installing it, the issue is solved. Thanks :)

Comment: fine, put in the answer your solution and sign it as answered:)